# Is this "during what ..." correct?

Tags: grammar

The following sentence was my answer in a english test:

> One is the familiar feeling that is acquired *during what* they experienced in the womb.

While the contents were correct, I was told that I had made a grammatical mistake in "*during what*". However, I do not see what the mistake is? Is there an error in the sentence? If so, what exactly is wrong and how would I correct it?

Comment: What is the quote trying to express? I see a noun phrase "what they experienced in the womb" - are you saying that the "familiar feeling" was "acquired" during that experience?

Comment: During refers to a time period. If you are using "during" you have to specify a time period (e.g. during the last week of 1945)  or something that refers to a time period (e.g. during their stay).

Comment: "what they experienced in the womb" is another way of saying "their experiences in the womb". If you replace "what they experienced" with "their experiences" the sentence will work perfectly well.